# Split an Array into multiple Strings Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My array looks like

`["John Connor ", "Mike ", "Ryan Jones ", "Markey O ", "Markey B"]`

I'm trying to put these into multiple strings (though splitting into multiple strings may not be the best way) so I can place them on the page one below the other.

So I do `$(".info_container").text(myArray);`

How can I split these at the `,` and then place them into the `DOM`?

I tried `$(".info_container").text(myArray).join(",");` but this still just gives me a string of arrays not individual strings.

Comment: This maybe will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks

Comment: instead of `$(".info_container").text(myArray).join(",");` try `$(".info_container").text(myArray.join(","));`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g4rat651/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var array = ["John Connor ", "Mike ", "Ryan Jones ", "Markey O ", "Markey B"];
array.forEach(function(name) {
   $(".info_container").append('<span>' + name + '</span>');
});
```

Comment: Cheers man! This worked. I didn't really think of doing a `forEach` over my array :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.innerHTML` with `arrary.join(', <br>')`:

```js
var arr = ["John Connor ", "Mike ", "Ryan Jones ", "Markey O ", "Markey B"];

document.body.innerHTML = arr.join(', <br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var myArray = ["John Connor ", "Mike ", "Ryan Jones ", "Markey O ", "Markey B"].toString();
```

Then:

```
$(".info_container").text(myArray);
```